# how to include a file containing variables in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, sh

i have many script shell and i want to include a file containing variables in this shell

script?

My var script:

```
###################################################################################
ORACLE_LOGIN=login
ORACLE_PWD=pwd
CHEMIN_1="/home/"
CHEMIN_2="/scripts/"
LOG_FILE="$CHEMIN_1/max.log"
export ORACLE_SID=oracle_sid
###################################################################################
```

My script sh:

```
#!/bin/ksh
#set -x

# ==============   LOAD VAR HERE  ====================================
????

##################################################################
####                          Begin                           ####
##################################################################

write "Begin $0"  

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s $ORACLE_LOGIN/$ORACLE_PWD@$ORACLE_SID <<EOF >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1 
@$CHEMIN_2/sp_rep_alim_dia_date_max.sql
exit
EOF

write "End."
```

Thx.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It depends which shell, but one of these two usually works:

```
. var
```

or

```
source var
```

I'm not sure about ksh, but I'd imagine both would work.

Comment: sh: line 5: fct_commun.sh: No such file or directory of this type

Comment: Does a file named "var" exist in the current directory?

Answer (score 5):

```
. ./name_of_the_var_script
```

That’s dot + space + dot + slash + filename (because the “dot” utility needs an absolute or relative path to your var script).

Comment: sh: line 5: fct_commun.sh: No such file or directory of this type

Comment: You do need to specify the correct path ("$(dirname "$0")" as below usually works).

Answer (score 2):

use the `.` (dot) command to source the file

```
. var_script
```

---

A note:

- if the filename *does not contain a slash* then bash will attempt to find it **in the $PATH**.
- if not found in the PATH, the **current directory** will be used (unless bash is in POSIX mode).

Ref [the `.` command][source] in the manual.

So, if you know where it is, use a relative/absolute path for it.
[source]: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_002e

Comment: sh: line 5: fct_commun.sh: No such file or directory of this type

Comment: If that file is in the same directory as the "main" script, then `. "$(dirname "$0")"/fct_commun.sh`

Answer (score 0):

`source var` worked for me.
this link [Pass all variables from one shellscript to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772036/pass-all-variables-from-one-shellscript-to-another) has good explanation for this problem

// Hope this helps..

Comment: Welcome to stack Overflow.. If this is an answer then provide useful information regarding this link as well.. Because comment in answer section is not allowed..