# Shell include path cannot be found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, capistrano

Following the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772036), I have the following for deployment:

```
$ ls -alh /etc/init.d
# unicorn_init_include.sh -> /home/deployer/abc/current/config/unicorn_init_include.sh
# unicorn_abc -> /home/deployer/abc/current/config/unicorn_init_staging.sh

# /home/deployer/abc/current/config/unicorn_init_staging.sh
#!/bin/sh
RAILS_ENV="staging"
export RAILS_ENV
unicorn_init_include.sh

# /home/deployer/abc/current/config/unicorn_init_include.sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e

TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT-60}
APP_ROOT=/home/deployer/abc/current
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT; bundle exec unicorn -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E $RAILS_ENV"
```

You will notice it's all symlinked when I `deploy:setup` with Capistrano:

```
executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' ln -nfs /home/deployer/abc/current/config/unicorn_init_staging.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_abc"
servers: ["192.168.33.10"]
[192.168.33.10] executing command
[out :: 192.168.33.10] 
command finished in 611ms
executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' ln -nfs /home/deployer/abc/current/config/unicorn_init_include.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_init_include.sh"
servers: ["192.168.33.10"]
[192.168.33.10] executing command
[out :: 192.168.33.10] 
command finished in 602ms
```

But when Capistrano tries to fire the command:

```
** [out :: 192.168.33.10] /etc/init.d/unicorn_abc: 4: /etc/init.d/unicorn_abc:
** [out :: 192.168.33.10] unicorn_init_include.sh: not found
```

I have tried changing the `unicorn_init_include.sh` in the `unicorn_init_staging.sh` to `./unicorn_init_include.sh`, symlinked the `unicorn_abc` to `/etc/init.d/` (as shown above), but it doesn't work.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try full path

change

```
export RAILS_ENV
unicorn_init_include.sh
```

to

```
export RAILS_ENV
/etc/init.d/unicorn_init_include.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your unicorn_init_staging.sh, 4th line. When the unicorn_abc is called it's not calling from the working directory /home/deployer/abc/current/config, but somewhere else, like /etc/init.d . So it won't find your unicorn_init_include.sh.

You can troubleshoot by adding

```
echo 'pwd'
```

to the staging.sh file

What is probably is needed is changing the staging file to (not tested)

```
#!/bin/bash
RAILS_ENV="staging"
export RAILS_ENV
`dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`/unicorn_init_include.sh
```

[Getting the source directory of a Bash script from within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in)