# Calling and returning a value from shell script using nohup

Tags: shell, ksh

I have two shell script files . One is a general file which install something on system and other is a file which processes some steps of installation.

file1: Main Installation file
file2: Installation assistance file

I am calling file2 from file1 using

```
 nohup ./file2.sh $1 </dev/null >../logs/schema.log 2>&1 &
 schema_status=$?
 echo $schema_status
```

Now because of nohup schema_status value is coming as 0 always.

How do I return a relevant value from file2 to file1 .

In file2, I have added a return statement:

```
if (condition)
then
   exit 101
else
   exit 102
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the link where a problem similar to your is discussed. It suggest you to export a environment variable in file1.sh and then set this environment variable in file2.sh. By this you will be able return(indirectly) from file2.sh to file1.sh

[Pass all variables from one shellscript to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772036/pass-all-variables-from-one-shellscript-to-another)

Answer (score 0):

When file1 is calling file2 and waits for the result, do not start file2 with nohup. When file2 takes a long time, you can start file1 with nohup.