# Pass all variables from one getops shellscript to another?

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

Assuming we have a getopts shell library, "command_line.sh":

```
while getopts  “c:” argv

do
     case $argv in

         c)
             CLIENT_ID=$OPTARG


             ;;
     esac
done

echo "CLIENT_ID is ${CLIENT_ID}"
```

How can we pass the above ${CLIENT_ID} from the above shell library to another script without using export as an environment variables??  I have tried some solutions in the following link, but none of them works

[Pass all variables from one shellscript to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772036/pass-all-variables-from-one-shellscript-to-another)

For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

. ./command_line.sh -c 1

echo "CLIENT_ID is ${CLIENT_ID}"
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh

./command_line.sh -c 1

echo "CLIENT_ID is ${CLIENT_ID}"
```

or tried in bash instead of sh

sadly none of them works.  Could any guru enlighten?  Thanks.

Comment: By the way replace both `“` by `"`.

Comment: in the getopt you mean?

Comment: I meant replace `“c:”` by `"c:"`.

Comment: @Cyrus suggestion works perfectly! Never think of the problem could be from “ !