# xargs with export is not working

Tags: bash, xargs

I have a file which looks as below.

```
HOST=localhost
PORT=8080
```

I want to export the above into environment. I am executing the following command to export the variables in file to environment.

`cat <FileName> | xargs export`

I am getting the following exception when trying to run the above command.

`xargs: export: No such file or directory`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass all variables from one shellscript to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772036/pass-all-variables-from-one-shellscript-to-another)

Answer (score 23):

Why use `xargs`? When you can just `source` the file in the current shell

You can use the `set` builtin, along with the `export` instead of using a non-shell built-in like `xargs`. Just do below

```
set -o allexport
. ./file_containing_variables
set +o allexport
```

The usage of `allexport` flag with you set(-o)/unset(+o) allows you to export variables directly from the command-line. The second line is the `POSIX` `source` (dot followed by variable name) command to reflect all variables to the *current* shell and within the `allexport` flag, it is made available permanently.

Refer [GNU `set` built-in](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) page for more details.

---

Another way in `bash` using input re-direction on the file

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    export "$line"
done <file_containing_variables
```

Comment: Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66780625/2202107

Answer (score 17):

It is possible to use `xargs` but you have to execute it as a sub-shell and use the `-L 1` option to pass back one line at a time.

```sh
export $(cat FileName | xargs -L 1)
```

This approach would allow you to do further string manipulation if you needed. For example you can remove spaces from the file.

```sh
export $(cat FileName | tr -d ' ' | xargs -L 1)
```

Comment: This approach works just until spaces appear in variable values, so it didn't work for me. The only solution that could cope with spaces was found here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/659951

Answer (score 7):

`export` is a built-in function, and `xargs` takes executable as an argument, not a function. Also, there is no sense in wrapping `export` into some script or subshell,  `xargs` won't fail in such case, but your vars won't be exported anyway. 
So better to choose some another approach, w/o `xargs`, like showed in the previous comment.

Answer (score 4):

Dieselist correctly explained the reasons why the original approach did not work. The approaches presented by Inian shall work, but a simpler way is (cf. [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)):

`export $(<FileName)`

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work with values that have spaces. One gets an error from export that reads: `export: not valid in this context`

Answer (score 0):

This will allow filtering or rewriting of the file and then run the export command on each line that is returned

```
for i in `cat <FileName> | grep " "`; do
  export $i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The best one to me is

```bash
export $(grep -v '^#' .env | xargs)
```

This command let you write the `.env` file and comment lines with `#`.
So it is compatible with your variable file and with

```
# This it the host 
HOST=localhost
# This is the port
PORT=8080
```