# Exporting an env-file with values containing space

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, command-line-arguments, quoting

I'm using environment files to configure web apps. Recently i had the need to export a value like this:

```
RUBYOPT='-W:no-derecated -W:no-experimental'
```

This is contained in a file `test.env` with other config vars.

I use this command to export all the env vars in the file:

```
export $(cat test.env | xargs)
```

With the value like above, the command gives this error:

```
-bash: export: `-W:no-experimental'': not a valid identifier
```

I can export the value by copy pasting the output of `cat test.env | xargs` but in a single command like above it doesnt work.

Some testing revealed, that the issue appears when the value contains a space   and somewhere after that a colon `:`.

What kind of quotation sorcery do I need to make my env-file work again?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The construct with `export $(cat test.env | xargs)` is very fragile and you get shell interpretation of the `'` characters (and other special characters) so  `RUBYOPT='-W:no-derecated -W:no-experimental'` therefore becomes `RUBYOPT=-W:no-derecated -W:no-experimental`. Note the missing `'`. This was not a problem until you set variables with space in them.

I recommend dropping this way of exporting all variables in the environment file.

If your `test.env` file contains assignments to variables in `bash` syntax, that are not `export`ed, you could instead turn on automatic exporting and then source the `test.env` file.

Example:

```
set -a      # turn on automatic exporting
. test.env  # source test.env
set +a      # turn off automatic exporting
```

From `BASH_BUILTINS` (`man set`):

`set -a` "*Each variable or function that is created or modified is given the export attribute and marked for export to the environment of subsequent commands.*"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using the mentioned command for a long time and would like to keep it. Also i'm very interested in what exactly makes `export $(cat test.env | xargs)` stumble here

Comment: @mikezter You're welcome. I added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: aah, so the colon `:` provoked an error message and made me aware of the problem, whereas a space in the value just failed silently (creating empty vars).

Comment: @mikezter The `:` shouldn't be a problem. It's the space in this case which makes the `export` command look like this: `export RUBYOPT=-W:no-derecated -W:no-experimental` and as you can see, `-W:no-experimental`, is not a part of the _value_ that is supposed to be assigned to `RUBYOPT`. It's interpreted as an identifier of its own. The `:` makes it an invalid identifier (pure luck) and so does `-`. Otherwise you'd have gotten a `RUBYOPT` with only the first assignment which can be very hard to realize and it can break builds etc.

Comment: `what exactly makes export $(cat test.env | xargs)` 1. Qoutes in values `a="\""` will result in error. 2. Multiline values will error. 3. Any other shell expressions will not work. 4. Backslashes will not be preserved inside single quotes. TBH I do not know why you use `xargs` here it all, it's just an error to use `xargs` here, `xargs` is not for that. 5. `cat file | cmd` is a useless use of cat. Use `< file cmd`. 6. The result of `$(..)` is _word splitted_ __and__ _filename expanded_. Spaces and tabs will not work. The will be a lot of strange issues with `*` `?` characters.

Comment: @mikezter KamilCuk brings forth a lot of reasons to _not_ go ahead with your current solution.

Comment: @mikezter Having used something for a long time is not a valid reason to perpetuate a bad practice.

Comment: ok ok i accpeted the answer and adjusted my habits :) Just for esoteric reasons, is there really no way to preserve quotes in a case like this `export $(echo TEST_VAR='my fancy value') `

Comment: @mikezter :-) That's great! The quotes could be perhaps be preserved by `sed`:ing `test.env`, but there are other things as KamilCuk mentioned. Building something taking care of all those cases will likely be error prone and it's much safer to let the shell do the interpretation. It's also faster to just turn on auto-`export` and source the file.