# Which is best way to use the variable in shell script

Tags: shell, variables, global-variables

I am using global variable as INSTALL_DIR='/tmp' and then am calling function to use that variable in shell script

Which is the correct method from the following to use the variable?

Method 1:-

```
INSTALL_DIR='/tmp'

install_app() {

 echo "application path - $INSTALL_DIR"

}

install_app
```

Method 2:-

```
INSTALL_DIR='/tmp'

install_app() {
 app=$1
 echo "application path - $app"
}

install_app $INSTALL_DIR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use variable in multiple places **with in same script**, then first approach is better.

But if variable will be **used in different scripts** , then you have to **Export** it (export will make it environment variable) in first script before using in second script. Refer to this link for exporting from one script to other.

[Pass all variables from one shellscript to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772036/pass-all-variables-from-one-shellscript-to-another)

For different scripts, use extra one-dot (.) to run  **. ./myscript.sh**, it will **execute within same scope**.