# Working with Variables in multiple files Shell Scripts

Tags: unix

While working with Config files (user defined variables in file) I need below requirement. I have variables in config files and need to read variables from files and order of precedence. Example as
given below

Main parameter (default) file.

```
    param.ini: 
    Var1=today
    Var3=xyz
```

Override parameter file (adhoc override changes)

```
    Param.override:
    var1=yesterday
    var2=123
```

My script as given below

```
    test.sh:
    . ~/param.override,~/param.ini

    echo "run day -> $var1"
```

Result i need is

```
    run day -> yesterday
```

I remember we can achieve this using dot operator or Source command in Unix. Please help me what will be syntax for script to call variable from multiple files.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772036/pass-all-variables-from-one-shellscript-to-another) help?

Comment: Unfortunately No!! as my requirement is more than one file has variable with the same name I need to control that value from config file not in the script. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This: works for me, not sure if you tried this?

```
$ cat param.ini
Var1=today
Var3=xyz

$ cat param.override
Var1=yesterday
var2=123

$ cat test.sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
. ~/cygwin/param.override ~/cygwin/param.ini

echo "run day -> $Var1"

$ ./test.sh
run day -> yesterday
```

Comment: Thanks A lot!! I tried with , : and ; between files. not tried with space.

Comment: did it, New to the forun:)