# How to export environment variable to background process run using sudo?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, sudo, environment

I have a bash script `env_setter.sh`. It sets an environment variable. It contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "inside env_setter script....."
export NAME="jake"
```

I have another script `tester.sh`. It tries to print the value of the environment variable set by `env_setter.sh`. It contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Inside tester script..."
echo "$NAME"
```

Then I have a script `runner.sh` that executes both of the above scripts as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Inside runner script..."
. ./env_setter.sh
echo "$NAME"
sudo nohup ./tester.sh > demo.log 2>&1 & echo $! > save_pid.pid
```

Now when I run `runner.sh`, I get following output in `demo.log`:

```
inside env_setter script.....
jake
Inside tester script...
```

As we can see, the last echo command in `tester.sh` doesn't print anything. This is because the environment variable that we set with `env_setter.sh` is not being exported inside the context of `tester.sh`.

So, how do I export the environment variable to the background process in such cases?

Comment: Normally sudo replaces the current environment with the environment of the user, for security reasons. Use `sudo -E` to preserve the calling environment. Or you can pass variables on the command line, `sudo NAME=jake`.

Comment: What you are looking for is to pass one variable from one script to another script. This has already been asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772036/pass-all-variables-from-one-shellscript-to-another

Comment: @JimJanney `sudo -E` worked for me. Thanks !

Comment: @JimJanney Would you please add that as an answer so the OP can check it off?  Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I export a variable to the environment from a bash script without sourcing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16618071/608639) and [How to keep environment variables when using sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8633461/608639)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally sudo replaces the current environment with the environment of the new user, for security reasons. Use `sudo -E` to preserve the calling environment. Or you can pass variables on the command line, `sudo NAME=jake`.